# Issue with Pattern and Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I have written code in Java to return a string of information in between two sequences of characters. My code is:

```
String caseDefendant = "vs."; 
Pattern caseDefendantPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(caseDefendant)+").*?(?=</span>)");
Matcher caseDefendantMatcher = caseDefendantPattern.matcher(pageContentString); 

while (caseDefendantMatcher.find()) {
    docketFile.write(caseDefendantMatcher.group().toString()); 
}
docketFile.write("^");
```

What I am trying to do is return the information in between `vs.` and `</span>`. This issue is that in the string "pageContentString" the sequence `vs.INFORMATION</span>` occurs twice, so when I go to write it to the file it is written twice instead of once, when I only need the information written once. For instance, If the pageContentString was:

```
"vs.info1</span>   aaabbbccc vs.info1</span>"
```

My file is written as `info1 info1`. How would I change my code so it would not write the second group of information?

Comment: You can always add a `break` after the `docketFile.write(...` line, right?

Comment: Do you have to use loop here? Can you just use `if` instead of `while`? Also `toString()` is not necessary in your code because `group` already returns String.

Comment: What happens if you take the caseDefendantMatcher.find() out of a while loop.  if you only want the first item found shouldn't you stop after the first match? Im hesitent with my Java regex :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a loop here:

```
while (caseDefendantMatcher.find()) {
    docketFile.write(caseDefendantMatcher.group().toString()); 
}
```

This loop will find and print all the matches. If you only want the first match then don't loop:

```
String caseDefendant = "vs."; 
Pattern caseDefendantPattern = Pattern.compile("(?<="+Pattern.quote(caseDefendant)+").*?(?=</span>)");
Matcher caseDefendantMatcher = caseDefendantPattern.matcher(pageContentString); 

if (caseDefendantMatcher.find()) {
    docketFile.write(caseDefendantMatcher.group().toString()); 
}

docketFile.write("^");
```